# Web View com zoom

Tags: java, html, android, webview

Tenho uma *web view* sendo carregada na tela (montado por um HTML interno) que as vezes abre com *zoom* e outras sem o *zoom*. Não quero que ela abra com *zoom*, preciso que ela abra na tela inteira!

Aqui o trecho do layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webViewReport"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_report"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Aqui carrego o HTML e jogo pro WV

```
montaHTML();

wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewReport);
ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ws.setSupportZoom(true);
ws.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
wv.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Pode precisar de um tag meta viewport na página para funcionar bem. Fica avisado que WebView no Android é sempre uma loteria, sempre tem uma chance do site não aparecer com o zoom pretendido, pois há pequenas diferenças de implementação entre versões do Android, fabricantes e modelos.

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar este método: `ws.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);`.
Ele define se o carregamento da página *WebView* será no modo de visão geral, afastando o conteúdo para caber na tela através da largura.

Referência:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html